# clearTimeout doesn't work with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Wrapper is the parent node and there is an input element as child node, the focusout event is used to execute some code when input lost focus, the onkeydown event is used to execute some code when Esc or Enter is pressed. When the Esc is pressed， the input will also lost focus, so it will call focusout event as well. For solve this issue, i use a settimeout method in focusout, and clear it in onkeydown event, it supposed to not call focusout event when press the Esc or Enter, but my code seems doesn't work, anyone can help? Thanks in advance!
HTML structure may like this:

```html
<div>
<input type="text">
</div>
```

```
Wrapper.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.scrElement;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       some code
    }, 120);

});
```

```
Wrapper.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.scrElement;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 13) {
            some code
        }
    }
}
```

i have also tried this way, add the event on input directly, but stil doesn't work

```
inp.onblur = function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            some code 
        }, 120);        
    }
```

```
inp.onkeydown = function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        var e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        console.log(target.parentNode);
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 27:
                some code
                break;
            case 13:
                some code
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

but in the same file, the clearTimeout works fine in the onclick event, the code has been shown below:

```
cancelBtn.onclick = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        somecode;
    }
```

the onclick and onkeydown function structure looks exactly same for me, but why it's only works in onclick event? This is really confused me, please help.

Comment: was timer defined outside the `addEventListener` callback ?

Comment: `e.scrElement;`  appears to be a typo - just here or in your actual code?

Comment: Please create a [MRE] within your question that clearly shows the issue.

Comment: why are you using `AddEventListener` in one place but `.on[event name]` in the rest?

Comment: @Morphyish yes, i have defined timer as global var

Comment: @MikeBrockington  sorry, it's just a typo...

Comment: @MattEllen cause onfocusout event doesn't work with .on[event name] style in chrome, so i use addEventListener

Comment: Can you check if the 'focusout' is being called when you hit the Esc key (keyCode 27)? Just tested on Chrome 75, neither the input field nor the wrapper loses focus when the Esc key is fired - the event only fires when I click manually outside the field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your code.

If you run a sequence:

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(1);
    }, 120);
timer = setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(2);
    }, 120);
clearTimeout(timer);
clearTimeout(timer);
```

A first code of setTimeout will be executed once.
First command sets new timer.
Second command adds new timer and overwrites timer id.
First clearTimeout cleans a second timer.
Second clearTimeout cant remove first timer because its value is gone.

I think that what is happened at the code.
To fix this issue you need to run a clean every time before setTimeout.

Comment: i have edited my question with another onclick event, which has the same structure with onkeydown, but the clearTimeout method is functional with onclick. so i guess the problem is not casued by your solutions, do you have any other suggertions? and I have tried to clear the timer everytime, but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: I supposed to place clearTimeout right before each setTimeout call to make sure you clear everything.
It is possible that few same events are fired before clear.   

To make sure what exactly happens, please, put console.log before setTimeout and cleanTimeout.

Comment: Also, onblur is called after onkeydown of the same element.
onclick of another element is fired after onblur of previous element.